# Main.js not found (SystemJS, Angular2)

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, systemjs

I've been upgrading my Angular2 RC4 app to the RC5 version, and I've suddenly run into this issue.

My app compiles fine, but when I load the page at `localhost:3001`, I get a 404 for my `main.js`.

I'm also using gulp.

This is my file structure:

```
.
+-- src
|   +-- app
|   |   +-- main.ts
|   |   +-- app.module.js
|   |   +-- app.component.ts
|   |   +-- app.component.html
|   |   +-- components <-- Directory
|   |   +-- services <-- Directory
|   |   +-- models <-- Directory
|   +-- system.config.js
|   +-- index.html
+-- tsconfig.json
+-- typings.json
```

This is my system.config.js:
js

```
(function (global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map            = {
        'app'      : 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular' : 'node_modules/@angular',
        'rxjs'     : 'node_modules/rxjs',
        '@models'  : 'app/models',
        '@services': 'app/services',
        '@model_services': 'app/services/model_services',
        'moment'   : 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
        'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages       = {
        'app' : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        '@models': {main: 'index'},
        '@services': {main: 'index'},
        '@model_services': {main: 'index'}
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router'
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Comment: In your systemjs.config.js file, Did you try changing from `'app' : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'js'},` to `'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },` ?

Comment: That's what it was originally.

Comment: You've shown us the folder structure for your `.ts` files.  Show us the path at which the browser tries to load `main.js` when the `404` occurs. Also show us the folder structure for the compiled `.js` files, or at least the correct path to `main.js`

Answer (score -1):

I ended up fixing it. I think it was actually a problem with gulp, as the dist folder was pretty messed up.

I ended up re-cloning the project and everything is ok now.